# ftp_put() error failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, upload, ftp, tmp

So i am trying to create a php on webhost allow client to upload files to the webhost then webhost  use ftp_put to upload file to another ftp server. The following function is used for upload the file.

```
    //upload ftp
    function ftp_upload($conn, $vid_name, $video){
    //get tmp file
    $file_tmp_name = $video['tmp_name'];
    echo $file_tmp_name;

    //combine name with extension name
    $server_file_name = $vid_name . "." .      pathinfo($video['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           //upload video
        $upload = ftp_put($conn, $server_file_name, $file_tmp_name , FTP_BINARY);
    return $upload;

}
```

However it keeps getting the error msg, 
Warning: ftp_put(/tmp/phpKOtNWK) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: No such file or director.

So i went to the file manager in the webhost under my subdomain, there is no such directory called tmp, and i don't have privilege to enter the root directory for the webhost.

appreciate for your helps.

Comment: Where does `$video['tmp_name']` come from?

Comment: First, I'd confirm that PHP reckons the file was uploaded successfully by checking the `error` index in `$video`. If PHP has managed to write it, I would expect it to be able to read it. Currently, it's sounding more like the file has been moved before this function is called.

Comment: $video = $_FILES['file'];

Comment: and yah the error index in $video is 0 which is no error at all. I used  session to store file then redirect to itself and pass session down to do the upload. do you think that might be the reason why it has been moved?

Comment: Don't use the temp name and I would not try to put `$_FILE` into `$_SESSION`. Complete handling the file upload fully, and then put the final path in your session. Use that final path in your `ftp_put`.

Comment: So now i used move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $new_location_in_server), then redirect the page, and use ftp_put($conn, $new_location_in_server, $location_for_ftp_server) and, dang, it worked. Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Twisty 23 and Jon Stirling's advices, i've solved the issue. Unfortunately noone posted answer(all comments) which bugs me to keep this unsolved, so i'll just answer myself. 
This is the code i used at the beginning to redirect

```
//store video information into session 
if(count($_POST) >0 ){           
    $_SESSION['vid_name'] = $_POST['vid_name'];
    $_SESSION['video'] = $_FILES['video'];

    //move tmp file to permanent location temp folder
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video']['tmp_name'], "./temp/" . $_POST['vid_name'] . ".tmp");

    //change tmp location to temp folder
    $_SESSION['video']['tmp_name'] = "./temp/" . $_POST['vid_name'] . ".tmp";

    //redirect
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
    die();

}
```

and then i don't need to change anything on ftp_upload function, i can use $_SESSION['video']['tmp_name'] straight away.